# Problems with ILNumerics plot drawing in OpenGL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, opengl, ilnumerics

I am using ILNumerics. I just tested some simple examples from the [ILNumerics website](http://ilnumerics.net/ilnumerics-interactive-web-component.html).

- If I choose to use the GDI renderer in the properties panel of the ILPanel control it works fine.
- If I choose the OpenGL renderer the scene is plotted wrongly, is blinking or is partially or not drawn.

I use VS2010 PRO, Win7 64-bit, Dell XPS 17 with Ge550M graphics.

Fogcity runs without problems using OpenGL. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the geforce card but some onboard graphic chip for rendering. Make sure, the NVIDIA card is used. Check the NVIDIA control panel.